# How can I appeal a closed question?

Tags: support, close-reasons

I asked a question [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/103536/recommendations-for-beginner-piano-pieces-that-make-equal-use-of-both-hands) and its reason for closing is... not even relevant to what the question is asking. It's so irrelevant that I'm having a difficult time defending against it outside of "the reason provided indicates the person who closed my question did not read the question or the reason for closing (or both)."

How can I appeal this?

Answer (score 3):

So to answer your core question, once a question is edited to fix the problems highlighted by the close reason it goes into a queue to be reviewed to be reopened. It does not guarantee the question will be reopened, but there is a process.

---

In this case the close reason is not the most helpful, but it is an artifact of us having 3 boiler plate close reasons that have to be applied to as many cases as possible. In this case the "finding specific song" part of the off topic close reason is what the close voters were signaling as finding specific songs to fit a criteria is off-topic. On the [on topic](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page in the don't ask page here is the specific relevant bullet point:

> Recommendations of pieces to listen to, study, or play, or that meet
> particular criteria

Comment: Would it make sense to open a Chat Room for getting piece recommendations? Piece recommendations to study and piece recommendations to listen to are very different from each other right? In a lot of ways recommendations to study come under practice and practice is there in the site's name.

But yeah Chat Rooms are kind of inactive in MusSE, But when closing such questions for being offtopic you could leave a link to that chat room in the comments maybe

Comment: We can add links to the chat room, but any user is free to do that whenever. The chat is a general resource that can be used for many things.